# Swift 4.1 unexpected result with NSMutableArray and index(of:)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9

I have a NSMutableArray of objects called Item.
I need to be able to get the index of an Item in the array given the Item itself.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct Item {
    var name: String
    var message: String
}

var itemsArray = NSMutableArray()

let item = Item (name: "name", message: "mex")
let item2 = Item (name: "name2", message: "mex2")

var items : [Item] = [item, item2]

itemsArray.addObjects(from: items)

itemsArray.index(of: item)
```

I get `9223372036854775807` as result of the last line.

What am I Missing?

edit: I am following a tutorial for UIPageViewController where NSMutableArray is needed to be able to get the index of an Item

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

if let currentPageViewController = viewController as? SinglePageViewController, let currentItem:Item = currentPageViewController.item {

    let currentIndex = itemsArray.index(of: currentItem)
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentIndex - 1)
}
return nil
}
```

taken from https://grokswift.com/pageviewcontroller/

edit2: sorry guys I did not want to upset everybody, actually I am just learning about PageViewController that instantiate a dynamic number pages based on data taken from JSon. 
I didn't think that following that tutorial was so bad.
If you can provide something bette (I know it is not really in topic) it would be helpful

Comment: That big number is `NSNotFound`.  Any reason why you want to use NSMutableArray instead of Swift Array only?

Comment: Why do you use `NSMutableArray` in Swift 4?

Comment: Since you're writing Swift, Do you have to work with `NSMutableArray`? why not  `var itemsArray: [Item]`?

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all – as mentioned many times – don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.

To be able to use `index(of` the struct must adopt `Equatable`.

in Swift 4.1 according to [SE-0185 Synthesizing Equatable and Hashable conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md) the `==` operator is synthesized just by adopting `Equatable`.

```
struct Item : Equatable
{
    var name: String
    var message: String
}

let item = Item (name: "name", message: "mex")
let item2 = Item (name: "name2", message: "mex2")

var items = [item, item2]

items.index(of: item) // 0
```

Comment: it was that simple! thank you! could you provide more info on why NSMutable is bad? I was just naively following a tutorial

Comment: There are two serious reasons: 1) Swift is based on a strong type system but Foundation collection types don't provide any type information 2) Unlike the immutable types `NSMutable...` collection types are not related to the Swift counterparts and cannot be bridged. And the keyword `var` makes any type mutable in Swift anyway.